# Log Extract: SED Command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I am trying to extract logs from my application within specific time-stamps. So i wrote the following script

```
a= echo $1 | sed 's/\//\\\//g';
b= echo $2 | sed 's/\//\\\//g';

sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" SystemOut.log;
```

Here a and b are the timestamps which i pass as parameters. When i run the script SED does not expand the variables.

But if i run the following script in terminal it works fine

```
sed -n '/6\/30\/14 9:03/,/6\/30\/14 9:04/p' SystemOut.log
```

Anyone can help?

I am running the script as following-

```
sh extract.sh '6/30/14 9:01' '6/30/14 9:03'
```

Comment: This `'6/30/14 9:01','6/30/14 9:03'` is being sent as one variable, commas are not field separators by default, so unless you have set it as one, this is one variable so $b doesn't exist in your sed statement.In future try echoing your variables before the part you think is a problem, and check if there is anything wrong with them :)

Comment: I corrected the mistake... But still the problem persists. It still does not expand the variables in the statement.

Comment: Another problem is the space after the `=`, which again you would have picked up if you had echoed the variables as suggested in my previous comment, there is nothing wrong with it not expanding, it is not being given anything to expand.

Comment: I am echoing the variables now as suggested. The variables a and b are giving the proper output as expected. But not in the SED command

    6\/30\/14 9:01
    6\/30\/14 9:03

Comment: Condorwasabis answer is correct, and is what i was trying to help you understand on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
a=$(echo $1 | sed 's/\//\\\//g');
b=$(echo $2 | sed 's/\//\\\//g');

sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" SystemOut.log;
```

In order to store the output of a command in a variable you can use $()

Comment: Solves the issue. Thanks. Strange the other way didnt work. I was echoing the variables and they were giving me the expected output but still didnt work in the SED command

Comment: Without the `$( ... )` process substitution (and the erroneous space after the equals sign) you were *only* echoing the values, not capturing into variables at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quote `""` to expand variable. like

```
sed -n "/\"$a\"/,/\"$b\"/p" SystemOut.log;
```

Comment: Still the same issue... It didnt expand